# Output of BatchNorm1d in PyTorch does not match output of manually normalizing input dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, batch-normalization, pytorctl

In an attempt to understand how `BatchNorm1d` works in PyTorch, I tried to match the output of `BatchNorm1d` operation on a 2D tensor with manually normalizing it. The manual output seems to be scaled down by a factor of 0.9747. Here's the code (note that affine is set to false):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable

X = torch.randn(20,100) * 5 + 10
X = Variable(X)

B = nn.BatchNorm1d(100, affine=False)
y = B(X)

mu = torch.mean(X[:,1])  
var_ = torch.var(X[:,1])
sigma = torch.sqrt(var_ + 1e-5)
x = (X[:,1] - mu)/sigma
#the ration below should be equal to one
print(x.data / y[:,1].data )
```

Output is:

```
0.9747
0.9747
0.9747
....
```

Doing the same thing for `BatchNorm2d` works without any issues. How does `BatchNorm1d` calculate its output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the reason. `torch.var` uses Bessel's correction while calculating variance. Passing the attribute `unbiased=False` gives identical values.